# How to avoid Xcode

Tags: xcode, game-engine, unreal-engine4

Good evening, unfortunately Xcode takes too much space on the hard drive, in my case - up to 25 Gigabytes, which is unacceptable for me, since apart from the game development -  I do other photography related work.

Therefore I would like to ask - is there a way to use Game Engines, let's take Unreal Engine 4 as an example, without Xcode, since the the disc space is crucial for my second job.

Comment: I'm inclined to say this is an opinion-based question. You can use another IDE instead of XCode if you'd like. You haven't given enough details to recommend an IDE to replace XCode, we have to assume you're even using macOS? This also seems like an XY problem because you could just move things to another drive and recover space for XCode.

Comment: Just buy an external 10TB disk (a LOT of photos), for under 10,859.80 rubles (cheap... your profile says Moscow). 25GB is only 1/40th of a TB, so that would be 1/400 of an 10TB disk drive, which is only 0.25% of the drive. That makes all your space concerns go away. You can keep the files you're actively editing on local flash disk for extra speed and you can get some pretty small external drives if you're using a notebook. Anyway an external disk or RAID array is certainly a lot easier than messing with XCode and its dependencies, and like you said, you need a lot of storage for photos.

Comment: This is not a programming problem. How to free up space on your hard drive is a hardware issue and this question should be asked on SuperUser or AskDifferent.

Comment: I do have 8Tb Drive, but it is too chunky to take it with me for long hikes. The question is not about freeing space, it is about using game engines without it, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could free up space inside the Settings > Mac Storage. You can delete support for devices you don't use.
[image: Mac Storage Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

An alternative IDE (Integrated Development Environment) you could use is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). It has support for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

[image: Visual Studio Code install website]

The [disk space required](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements) to install is less than 1GB. It is **free** to download and use.

To change your default source code editor in Unreal Engine 5, go to `Edit->Editor Preferences->General->Source Code->Source Code Editor` and select Visual Studio Code.

[image: Change source editor in UE5]

You will then have to restart the editor in order for the changes to take effect.

[image: Restart editor]

You may get a popup asking if you want to install the C++ extension pack. I would recommend adding this pack, and it doesn't take up too much additional space.

[image: C++ Pack]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does it compare doing app development to XCode?

Comment: Visual Studio Code doesn't have all of the features like Visual Studio or XCode, but it's still a good thing to try if you are short on space. If you are developing iOS games/apps you will probably still need to use XCode at some point.

Comment: "Visual Studio Code is a less bulky version of Visual Studio" -- This is a misleading statement. They have very little in common and provide different tools for different tasks. The similarity between them is just that they both have text/code editing with Intellisense.

Comment: @Romen you are right, although I think the OP really only wanted the basic text/code editing. Nevertheless I adjusted my answer and removed that comment.